# React - How to create Chained Cascading Helper Functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How could I chain helper methods in React?

I have a `helper.js` file with helper functions.

ie: *(ps: bellow are just mundane methods to illustrate my issue for now)*

```
//helper.js

export function handleLog(arg) {
  return console.log(`App current state is: ${arg}`);
}

export function handleSlice(arr) {
  return arr.slice(1, 2);
}

export function handleShuffle(arr) {
  return arr.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
}
```

I'm able to apply the methods to my React app as:

```
import { handleLog, handleSlice, handleShuffle } from "./helpers";
...

class Heros extends PureComponent {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      heros: ["Hulk", "Thor", "Aquaman", "Stan Lee"]
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { heros } = this.state;
    const shuffledheros = handleShuffle(heros);
    const strongestHero = handleSlice(shuffledheros);
    handleLog(heros);

    /* How could I chain  */
    // const strongestHero = handleShuffle(heros).handleSlice(heros);

    return (
      <>
        <h1>Chained Helpers</h1>
        Strongest: {strongestHero}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

**How could I chain ie:** `handleShuffle(heros).handleSlice(heros)` and so on?

- When chaining the second method it throws:
  `(0 , _helpers.handleSlice)(...).handleSlice is not a function`

I've unsuccessfully attempted refactoring the helpers to:

```
const helpers = {
 f1() { ...do something...; return this;},
 f2() { ...do something...; return this;}
}
export default helpers
```

That didn't work either. Here is the full [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/9jox75nn4r)

Answer (score 2):

You could create a custom class which can hold an array as an internal property to achieve this:

```js
class arrayUtils {
  constructor(items = []) {
    this._data = items;
  }
  reverseIt() {
    this._data.sort((a, b) => b - a)
    return this
  }
  getfirstTwo() {
    this._data.splice(0, 2)
    return this
  }
  printIt() {
    console.log('printing:', this._data)
    return this
  }
  get value() {
    return this._data
  }
}

// Create the instance
var arr = new arrayUtils([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

// Chain subsequent calls (since we return `this`)
console.log('chain:', arr.reverseIt().printIt().getfirstTwo().printIt())

// get the value
console.log('value:', arr.value)
```

You can see it [working here](https://repl.it/@akrion/ReactHelperClass)

Specifically to React you can have this in a separate class in a separate util file  and simply `export default` it:

```
class helpers ...

export default helpers
```

then import and create an instance:

```
import helper from './helper';

// Create the instance
var arr = new helper([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Comment: Could you pls show me how this approach would be wired to React?

Comment: Sure see the attached link to the answer.

Comment: Thank you! This is interesting and a brand new territory to me. I'm still raw on OOP paradigms.

Answer (score 1):

First: [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) doesn't return any array.

You should rewrite your function `handleShuffle`

```
export function handleShuffle(arr) {
  return arr.concat().sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
}
```

Second: you try to call array functions, but `Array` doesn't contain any `handleShuffle` or `handleSplice` functions. So you should run function by function:

```
const strongestHero = handleShuffle(handleSlice(heros));
```

[Your forked example](https://codesandbox.io/s/mm5ql2n5jj)

Comment: The provided fork does not execute `handleShuffle` only `handleSlice`. I'm also confused about why the need for `concat` ? My shuffling method is working I just can't chain them together.

Comment: we need concat because `sort` function is not return anything. I gived link for explanation

Comment: ```handleShuffle(handleSlice(heros));``` I executed two function step by step

Comment: the issue is that your suggestion isn't `shuffling` the array. It only returns the `same value` on each page reload.

Comment: Indeed. Why would the order matter on this case? How could I implement cascading methods  `f1().f2().f3()` and so on?

Comment: Because I'm slice array first and shuffle array with 1 element

Comment: You cannot call cascade function on array, because `Array` not containg those methods. You can call function by function (as my example). Or you can extend `Array.prototype` with your methods, but I don't think this is good idea.

Comment: You can use `lodash` as you wish. But code anyway will be like this: `slice(shuffle(array))`

Comment: Added another answer with `Array.prototype` extending

Comment: Yeah, the idea is to be able to chain methods such as `lodash, underscore, jquery, etc` but with my custom helpers

Comment: `lodash` executing function too: ```get(first(```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution: create Array prototype's methods:

```
Array.prototype.handleSlice = function() {
    return this.slice(1, 2);
};

Array.prototype.handleShuffle = function() {
    return this.concat().sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
};
```

So you can execute your methods as cascade.

```
heros.handleShuffle().handleSlice();
```

But I'm think that Array extending for those simple functions is not best idea.